# What can we conclude given that A is independent of B but not C?

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Suppose A and C are dependent random variables. If B is independent of A, can one conclude that B is also independent of C?

Comment: Try to make you'r question more clear. Are you talking about events, or polynoms, or vectors?

Comment: I think there's an error in the text...

Comment: surely the question should be "can one conclude that B is also independent of C?"

Comment: Try $A$ and $B$ independent non-constant random variables and $C=A+B$

Comment: Thanks guys for wonderful comments, it is night here in Kenya. I would have said have wonderful night.